# Public library captive portal connection

Tags: network-configuration

I'm trying from a few days ago to run Tor Browser in my library public connection, but although I tried a lot of methods I found on the internet, I was unable to connect trough Tor. I have two OS's: windows 10 and tails. I have downloaded tails because I have read about the trick of connect to the authentication page with the unsafe browser before start Tor. The unsafe browser connects without problems, but it doesn't work with the Tor Browser. Also I tried to use bridges, and I have tried with all the pluggable transports listed, and I didn't had success with any of them. Just today I discovered that the captive portal of my library takes the ip's  of the tor connection like a "malware site", so, I think the problem is there. I say that because I have entered the onion circuit ip in the unsafe navigation tab and I got this message:

http://194.109.206.212/
is in the category Malicious Websites 
Your FortiGate Administrator has blocked this category

Really I think I have tried all the solutions that I found in the tor and tails documentation, so, I will really appreciate your help with that. I need a way to use Tor browser with my connection.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [bridges with pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#PluggableTransports).

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is filtered on *at least* by-ip basis, so you need to use not just bridges with a pluggable transports, but I do recommend you to find an unpublished bridge or make your own unpublished bridge: if they are so persistent in blocks, not just Tor node list,but a bridge list can be banned as well. It's not as simple as a node list, but you can get the bridge list without solving a discrete logarithm problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you know how can I get an unpublished bridge? Or where can I find a guide to make my own bridge?

Comment: I can guide you in making this kind of bridge. You can start with making a relay at your home, I'll give you the configs after. Do you need a step-by-step guide?

Comment: Would be nice to have a step-by-step guide. If it's possible, of course.

Comment: yes it's possible, I'll make it for you tomorrow - quite a busy time today. I'll update my answer with it

Comment: Ok. Sure. I will wait for your answer.